# How set the validation between start date and end date should select with in the 3 years

Tags: javascript, react-datepicker, react-dates, react-datetime, react-daterange-picker

I am new to react JS, how can I achieve the validation between two date fields in React JS.

for example: End dates should allow to select only within 3 years based on start date.

```
class MyForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { startdate: '', enddate: '' };
    }
    mySubmitHandler = (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      alert("You are submitting " + this.state.startdate +"and"+ this.state.enddate);
    }
    myChangeHandler = (event) => {
      this.setState({startdate: event.target.value});
    }
    myEndDate = (event) => {
        this.setState({enddate: event.target.value});
      }
    render() {
      return (
        <form onSubmit={this.mySubmitHandler}>
        <img src="is.jpg"></img>
        <h2>Please select the Date range of .CSV </h2>
        <input
          type='date'
          onChange={this.myChangeHandler}
        />
        <span>   </span>
       <input
          type="date"
          onChange={this.myEndDate}
        />
        <h6 id="light">Note: Only up to 3 years worth of Data can be downloaded</h6>
        <div>
        {this.state.startdate && this.state.enddate && <input
      type='submit' value="Download" class="bi bi-cloud-arrow-down"  style={{ width: '10%', height: 30}}
    />}
        </div>
        </form>
      );
    }
  }
 
  ReactDOM.render(<MyForm />, document.getElementById('root'));

  export default MyForm;
```

Comment: You can set a [`min/max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#additional_attributes)-attribute on a date input field. Just set the values on change of the start-date for the end-date field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (startDate) {
    var maxDate = startDate;
    maxDate = format(addMonths(startDate, 36), " E MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss ");
    var strToDate = new Date(maxDate);
    console.log("maxDate value ==" + maxDate);
  }
```

**end date** will add **36** months from **start date**, then user able to selected within that period.

then convert the string to date format and then **strToDate** use in into datepicker tag.

```
<DatePicker id="endDate-css" placeholderText={END_DATE} dateFormat='dd-MM-yyyy' selected={endDate} minDate={startDate} maxDate={strToDate} onChange={handleEndDate}/>
```